# MATLAB calculate angle of rotation

Tags: matlab, transform, mathematical-optimization, least-squares, numerical-analysis

I have 5 points on a circle:..........1
   ...................................  ......... 2          ......     . 3

```
                      4     5
```

Now I have its rotated image: .............

.............................................................1.   .......3

```
                           2          5

                             4
```

Note: the points aren't numbered.

I basically have 5 sets of coordinates, which when plotted look like the below image.

I need to calculate the amount by which i have to tilt the image so as to make it look like the above image

Comment: @Andrey: It is rotate only. and i don't know the coordinates (xt,yt). I just know that the coordinates on rotation need to look like the above image

Comment: In that case you should start by finding the coordinates of some points in the input and output.

Comment: Is your data an *image* or a set of *points*?

Comment: My data is the coordinates of a set of points. The 2nd picture is just the plot of these coordinates. All I know is that, by rotating the coordinates(or the axis itself) through some angle, it can be transformed into the first pic(none of the coordinates of the first pic are known)

Comment: About the first image, what I do know: 4 of the 5 points can be joined to get a square(with its sides aligned with x,y-axes), and the fifth point lies above the centre of the square

Answer (score 1):

If you have the points coordinates, you can try minimizing the error by defining an appropriate functional of error, that depends on angle and offset.

This problem becomes solvable by linear least squares method if you also have a scale in your transform. In that case, the solution in Matlab is easy:

Let x,y be your original points, and xt,yt the result points.

```
   tform = cp2tform([x,y],[xt,yt],'linear conformal');
```

This transform can be applied on the image using `imtransform`

---

In case you model does not have scale, and it is rotate and shift only, you can find an approximate solution by the following least squares equations:

```
   ( x1   y1  1  0)                      (x1t)
   (-y1   x1  0  1)                      (y1t)
   ( x2   y2  1  0)                      (x2t)
   (-y2   x2  0  1) * ( cos(theta) )     (y1t)
          ...         ( sin(theta) ) = 
          ...         (    xc      )
          ...         (    yc      )

   (xn   yn  1   0)   
   (-yn  xn  0   1)                       (ynt)
```

Obviously, you can't force cos(theta) and sin(theta) to have the same theta, so the solution is approximate. It can serve as an initial solution and refined by gradient descent method.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Statistics Toolbox, I think the `procrustes` command might do what you need. Given two sets of points, it finds the best (in terms of a sum of squared errors) linear transformation (translation, reflection, orthogonal rotation, and scaling) of the points in one to conform them to the points in the other.

You can suppress the scaling and reflection components using optional inputs to the command. If you translate both sets to a common origin before applying the command, you would also suppress the translation component, and be left with just a rotation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question, this is the *absolute orientation problem*. You can find several solutions for it (*e.g.* Horn's solution using quaternions). A similar question can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23197/finding-a-rotation-transformation-from-two-coordinate-frames-in-3-space).